# Redirecting viewers to other site based on country geoip

Tags: nginx, geoip

let's say I have a website (www.abc.com/featured/abc) and wanted to redirecting (only that link) the viewer from other country except Malaysia to youtube video.. But www.abc.com is still worldwide. And yes, my server is already compiling with geoip module.

here is what i did in etc/nginx/sites-available/abc.com

```
location featured/abc/ {
  if ($geoip_country_code != "MY") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaMuQPmzrrU;
  }
}
```

but it still not working. Do I did somewhere wrong in the code

Answer (score 3):

Try map variable like this:

```
http {
...
map $geoip_country_code $georedirect {
  default 0;
  MY 1;
}
...
}

server {
...
location /featured/abc/ {
  if ($georedirect) {
    return 301 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaMuQPmzrrU;
  }
}
...
}
```

More info:
[Module ngx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)

Comment: Does this actually work ? What about on websites with many many users ?