# DNS - Domains - Multiple A records

Tags: dns, ip, domainservices

I'm sorry for maybe stupid question and my English grammar)
I'm software developer and I started my little startup.
Now I have users from USA, Israel, Russian Federation etc...

And I have 1 problem.
Now in Russian Federation started block Amazon IP's because Telegram application.

And now users from Russia cannot see my website and use my mobile app because my API and website use Amazon servers (EC2)

My question is: 
If i will run additional server in another hosting provider (in Germany or in Russian )
Can I on DNS level add 1 more A record?
Or how i can to redirect user by country?
For example :
If user A coming from Russia - this request going to Russian server, another to Amazon.

Again - I'm software developer and know nothing about DNS. So sorry if I asked something stupid)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something more than just DNS records. Such as a load balancing proxy.

Have a look at nginx https://www.nginx.com/ for instance, it could be part of a solution for you.

[Redirecting viewers to other site based on country geoip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140418/redirecting-viewers-to-other-site-based-on-country-geoip)